# Plugin Update History

Tags: plugins, logging

is there a way to check the update history of plugins, i.e. when a certain plugin was updated and from which version to which?

Thanks.

Comment: WordPress does not keep a record of this information.

Comment: If you're looking at plugins in the official WP repository, you can check out their Trac information (eg https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/akismet#tags), but it's a pretty manual process and I don't know of an automated way to do it.